# Define macro for UIFont doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want define a macro for unifying all fonts in my app:

```
#define EXO_REGULAR_FONT(size) [UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" size:size]
```

and than using this macro like this:

```
myLabel.font = EXO_REGULAR_FONT(15);
```

But the compiler give me this error:

[image]

(there is an arrow under 15).

Any ideas to resolve ? Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the name of your parameter:

```
#define EXO_REGULAR_FONT(theFontSize) [UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" size:theFontSize]
```

From [GCC manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html):

> When the macro is expanded, each use of a parameter in its body is replaced by the tokens of the corresponding argument

So when your macro is expanded, it inserts this in your code, hence the compilation error:

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" 15:15]
```

Comment: what is possible solution for swift-4 ?

Comment: @Anita see Nikolai's answer bellow and the its comments. A good way to do this in Swift would be to add it as an extension to UIFont.

Answer (score 5):

```
#define EXO_REGULAR_FONT(size) [UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" size:size]
```

gets expanded, when you call `EXO_REGULAR_FONT(15)`, to

```
[UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" 15:15]
```

So you need to define it like this for example:

```
#define EXO_REGULAR_FONT(_size_) [UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" size:_size_]
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use a macro; they are evil (you did just experience one of the many reasons).

Use a function instead:

```
static inline UIFont *ExoRegularFont(CGFloat size) {
   return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" size:size];
}
```

Comment: Would be bad practice to keep this in something similar to macros.h and attach it in your pch?

Comment: @BooRanger Not at all. Definitely much better and safer than the `#define`.

Comment: a category on UIFont would also be a good way to handle custom fonts. Similar to `+systemFontOfSize:` I use `+appFontOfSize:`, `+boldAppFontOfSize:`, `+headingFont`, ... in my apps.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch You should add this comment as a new answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
#define EXO_REGULAR_FONT(s) [UIFont fontWithName:@"Exo-Regular" size:s]
```