# How to create a macro [UIFont fontWithName:size:]?

Tags: objective-c, macros, uifont

I use this macro:

```
#define fontMacro(name, size) ((UIFont *)[UIFont fontWithName:(NSString *)(name) size:(CGFloat)(size)])

UIFont *font = fontMacro(@"Akrol", 15); // Error: Expected ']'
UIFont *font2 = ((UIFont *)[UIFont fontWithName:(NSString *)(@"Akrol") size:(CGFloat)(15)]); // work fine
```

So, how can I use `fontMacro`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Define macro for UIFont doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339461/define-macro-for-uifont-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `size` argument of your macro is expanded at *all occurrences* of "size" on the right hand side, so that `fontMacro(@"Akrol", 15)` expands to

```
((UIFont *)[UIFont fontWithName:(NSString *)(@"Akrol") 15:(CGFloat)(15)])
                            unwanted expansion here ---^
```

Renaming the macro argument to `_size_` or similar 
should solve the problem:

```
#define fontMacro(_name_, _size_) ((UIFont *)[UIFont fontWithName:(NSString *)(_name_) size:(CGFloat)(_size_)])
```